# Swagger NodeJS File Upload

Tags: node.js, file-upload, swagger, postman, cloudinary

**Solution:**
Had an error in my swagger contract, correct definition of a fileupload should look like this:

```
  parameters:
   - in: formData
     name: file
     description: The file to upload
     required: true
     type: file
```

Thank you for the hint!

**Original question:**

I have a problem regarding my Swagger/NodeJS API.

I want to receive fileuploads and store the retrieved file with another cloud service.

Sadly, the file does not arrive in the format I expect it to be.
This is what I receive in *req.swagger.params.image.value* via postman:

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryZCFoUQnf4lHIhzjj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="r14kvzvmsh3xnuyl2vq8.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG

IHD�o&�IDA�c���?� � ��1��X��5�юIEND�B`�
------WebKitFormBoundaryZCFoUQnf4lHIhzjj--
```

The tested image [as a PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTetQ.png) or as base64:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

My cloudprovider for the images is cloudinary, so when I use the following code it is successfully saved to the service.

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
```

When I use

```
new Buffer(req.swagger.params.image.value, 'binary').toString('base64');
```

I expected the file to be converted to base64, but I think the part in the req defining the Content-Type etc. is also converted.

Does anybody know a way to work with fileuploads and swagger, so I can upload the image successfully to cloudinary?

Regex seems very "hacky"...

This is the imageupload part in my swagger contract:

```
/imageUpload:
x-swagger-router-controller: image_upload
post:
  description: Endpoint to upload the image file. The image has to be uploaded before the shipment is created, a response will be the image ID that has to be supplied to the shipment. If the image ID is not valid, i.e. not known to this api, the shipment can not be created
  operationId: storeImage
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data
    - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    - binary
  parameters:
   - in: body
     name: image
     description: The file to upload
     required: true
     schema:
        type: string
        format: file
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        # a pointer to a definition
        $ref: "#/definitions/ImageResponse"
    # responses may fall through to errors
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint, that did it, will edit my question to show the solution.

Comment: Awesome. I'll write that ^ in an answer too.

Comment: I am using your 'correct definition' but still, it is not converted to base64.
where to define base64 in the swagger doc? I didn't any base64 on your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're uploading the raw binary image instead of the base64 encoded image. I'd do away with all the binary stuff, define only base64 in your swagger doc, and ensure the Buffer->base64 encoding is working as expected (do some console logging).

Comment: where to give base64 in swagger UI doc? I didn't see any base64 in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

2021 Update:

Swagger does not allow file upload with the method above. `consumes` field doesn't exist anymore.

New version is like this:

```
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            fileName:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

Comment: I tried this method but it is not showing option to select file for upload

Comment: Yes, It doesn't show options. However, I couldn't find any other way to upload files. I wonder why Swagger removed the working method...

Comment: yes, the old method, maybe try clicking on try it out, I thought it doesn't work until I clicked it